# How to benefit from `.BY` in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

This is the explanation in manual of `.BY`

> `.BY` is a list containing a length 1 vector for each item in `by`. This can be useful when `by` is not known in advance. The `by` variables are also available to `j` directly by name; useful for example for titles of graphs if `j` is a plot command, or to branch with `if()` depending on the value of a group variable.

It says "useful for example for titles of graphs if `j` is a plot command, or to branch with `if()` depending on the value of a group variable."

But still, I'm not sure when to use.how to benefit from this `.BY`?

Could you give one example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a SO/real-life example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22694260/817778

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple example. We are using the `.BY` variable to show which group the plot belongs to. Note that you can also do it without using `.BY`, by replacing it with `gear[1]`, which will be equivalent.

```
library(data.table)
mtcars_dt = data.table(mtcars)
mtcars_dt[,
  plot(wt, mpg, main = paste('Gears: ', .BY)),
  gear
]
```

Comment: note that `gear` is already of length one in that setting, so you don't need `gear[1]`, just `gear` will do

Comment: You are right. I thought that `gear` will be in the subsetted data frame, but apparently not.

Comment: it's inefficient to keep it as a vector as it's the same value and R will recycle the scalar as needed

Comment: @Ramnath, could you give one example about `branch with if() depending on the value of a group variable.`? thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding [eddi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511301/how-to-benefit-from-by-in-data-table#comment34252620_22512179), see also the [`data.table` FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html), **Inside each group, why are the group variables length-1?** "[...] `x` is a grouping variable and (as from v1.6.1) has length 1 (if inspected or used in `j`). It's _for efficiency and convenience_."