# findInterval() with varying intervals in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, intervals

I have asked this question a long time ago, but haven't found the answer yet. I do not know if this is legit in stackoverflow, but I repost it.

I have a data.table in R and I want to create a new column that finds the interval for every price of the respective year/month.

*Reproducible example:*

```
set.seed(100)
DT <- data.table(year=2000:2009, month=1:10,  price=runif(5*26^2)*100)
intervals <- list(year=2000:2009, month=1:10, interval = sort(round(runif(9)*100)))
intervals <- replicate(10, (sample(10:100,100, replace=T)))
intervals <- t(apply(intervals, 1, sort))
intervals.dt <- data.table(intervals)
intervals.dt[, c("year", "month") := list(rep(2000:2009, each=10), 1:10)]
setkey(intervals.dt, year, month)
setkey(DT, year, month)
```

I have just tried:

- merging the `DT` and `intervals.dt` data.tables by month/year,
- creating a new `intervalsstring` column consisting of all the V* columns to
  one column string, (not very elegant, I admit), and finally
- substringing it to a vector, so as I can use it in `findInterval()` but the solution does not work for every row (!)

So, after:

```
DT <- merge(DT, intervals.dt)
DT <- DT[, intervalsstring := paste(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10)]
DT <- DT[, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10") := NULL]
DT[, interval := findInterval(price, strsplit(intervalsstring, " ")[[1]])]
```

I get

```
> DT
      year month     price               intervalsstring interval
   1: 2000     1 30.776611 12 21 36 46 48 51 63 72 91 95        2
   2: 2000     1 62.499648 12 21 36 46 48 51 63 72 91 95        6
   3: 2000     1 53.581115 12 21 36 46 48 51 63 72 91 95        6
   4: 2000     1 48.830599 12 21 36 46 48 51 63 72 91 95        5
   5: 2000     1 33.066053 12 21 36 46 48 51 63 72 91 95        2
---                                                            
3376: 2009    10 33.635924 12 40 45 48 50 65 75 90 96 97        2
3377: 2009    10 38.993769 12 40 45 48 50 65 75 90 96 97        3
3378: 2009    10 75.065820 12 40 45 48 50 65 75 90 96 97        8
3379: 2009    10  6.277403 12 40 45 48 50 65 75 90 96 97        0
3380: 2009    10 64.189162 12 40 45 48 50 65 75 90 96 97        7
```

which is correct for the first rows, but **not** for the last (or other) rows.
For example, for the row 3380, the price ~64.19 should be in the 5th interval and not the 7th. I guess my mistake is that by my last command, finding Intervals relies only on the first row of `intervalsstring`.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at `?data.table` and made sure you understand each and every argument?   I only looked at this question briefly and my first thought is wondering if you know about `roll`, `which` and maybe `foverlaps()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your main problem is that you just didn't do `findInterval` for each group. But I also don't see the point of making that large merged `data.table`, or the `paste`/`strsplit` business. This is what I would do:

```
DT[, interval := findInterval(price,
                              intervals.dt[.BY][, V1:V10]),
     by = .(year, month)][]
#      year month     price interval
#   1: 2000     1 30.776611        2
#   2: 2000     1 62.499648        6
#   3: 2000     1 53.581115        6
#   4: 2000     1 48.830599        5
#   5: 2000     1 33.066053        2
#  ---                              
#3376: 2009    10 33.635924        1
#3377: 2009    10 38.993769        1
#3378: 2009    10 75.065820        7
#3379: 2009    10  6.277403        0
#3380: 2009    10 64.189162        5
```

Note that `intervals.dt[.BY]` is a keyed subset.

Comment: Nice `.BY` example.  Added to https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1363.