# R: How to bin efficiently using time-varying breakpoints?

Tags: r, dplyr, binning

I'm working with a large data frame of 14 million rows, containing columns `month`, `firmID`, and `firmSize`. In a separate data frame I have monthly breakpoints (quintiles essentially) for firm size.

My goal is to add a fourth column `quintile` to the first data frame. In this column I would have a number from 1 to 5 corresponding to the size quintile the `firmSize` belongs to in that specific month.

I have the following loop that does the job but has a runtime of several hundreds of hours.

```
for (i in 1:length(df$month)) {
  for (j in 1:4) {
    if (df$size[i] <= breakpoints[which(df$month[i] == breakpoints$month),(j+1)]) {
      df$quintile[i] <- j
      break()
    }
    else {
      df$quintile[i] <- 5
    }
  }
}
```

I have quite limited knowledge of e.g. the applications of dplyr and I was wondering if anyone has an idea about how to approach this problem so that I don't have to keep my laptop running for weeks.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Example data for the data frames: *(thank you Ricardo for your suggestion!)*

df

```
month  firmID   firmSize
201001 46603210 9738635
201001 72913210 1166077
201001 00621210 3884422
201512 75991610 2932127
201512 45383610 1241272
201512 05766520 1931038
```

breakpoints

```
month  Q1     Q2      Q3      Q4      Q5
201001 322770 1038300 2112300 4597580 28919700
201512 379340 1239800 2840630 7785700 46209140
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should include your data so we can run code with, paste the output from `dput(breakpoints)` and `dput(df[sample(1:10000000, 30, TRUE),])` (this last one will return some random rows from `df`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if using `findInterval` and `data.table` might be worth pursuing and faster. This was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694260/3460670) which I thought was very helpful.

`findInterval` finds the index of one vector in another (assuming the other is non-decreasing). In this case, `breakpoints` columns from `Q1` to `Q5` forms the second vector, and the function will return the index based on the `firmSize` value in the first data frame.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
setkey(df, month)

setDT(breakpoints)
setkey(breakpoints, month)

df[, quintile := findInterval(firmSize, breakpoints[.BY][, Q1:Q5]) + 1, by = month][]
```

**Output**

```
    month   firmID firmSize quintile
1: 201001 46603210  9738635        5
2: 201001 72913210  1166077        3
3: 201001   621210  3884422        4
4: 201512 75991610  2932127        4
5: 201512 45383610  1241272        3
6: 201512  5766520  1931038        3
```